# What restrictions can be expected travelling UK -> Cuba -> USA?

Tags: usa, uk-citizens, cuba

I am a British citizen and I'm planning to travel from the UK to Cuba, stay for a couple of days and then fly directly to Orlando from there. I will then fly back to the UK from Orlando. (Note: this is not a trip operated by a third party, I will be booking flights and accommodation myself).

There have been many threads about this on TripAdvisor in the past, with some people suggesting that American citizens have to declare the reason for their visit and that the same applies to a British citizen travelling from the USA to Cuba.

However, I am struggling to find information for travel in the reverse direction (Cuba to USA) for British citizens. A lot of the information online seems to have been given prior to Trump's amendments to the [policy regarding travel to Cuba](https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/sanctions/Programs/Documents/cuba_fact_sheet_11082017.pdf).

I'd like a more concrete idea of the procedure and if there are any other documents (besides ESTA for the USA and Cuban tourist card) that I might need.

Comment: There are significant difficulties in flying between the US and Cuba.  It can be done but there are hoops to jump through.  Have you considered flying to, say, Toronto first and then to Orlando, or just returning to the UK from Toronto or Havana?

Comment: @JimMacKenzie We did consider flying to Toronto first but obviously that means travelling further North to come back down again adding expense that we'd rather avoid. When you say there are "significant difficulties" could you try to elaborate on what these might be? I am aware of difficulties travelling from USA -> Cuba but not the other way around.

Comment: My understanding is that all flights between the US and Cuba right now require a license from the US State Department for travel, and are only available to US citizens and residents.  While it is trivial to fly from Cuba to Canada (even my small city has weekly non-stop flights weekly in winter), the average person cannot just simply book a flight to a US airport from Cuba, or vice versa, without documenting permission from the US government to be there.  I know this is getting less difficult, but it is not as simple as just finding an airline and booking a flight.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie Thanks a lot for elaborating. I suppose what I'm struggling to understand is why I am able to go to an airline's website (let's say JetBlue) as a UK citizen and I'm easily able to go through the booking process without any warnings or errors. The only thing JetBlue makes you do is tick to state your reason for travel being one of a number of categories.

Comment: Perhaps things have changed more than I think they have.  Now you just have to find someone who's flown the route who can confirm that it's as easy as it looks.

Comment: Airlines will let you book because ultimately responsibility for ensuring you have the correct visa(s) rests with the traveller, not the airline. The US applies its sweeping concept of extra terrestrial jurisdiction to many areas, travel between Cuba and US by foreign nationals being one of them. https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/sanctions/Programs/Documents/guidance_cuba_travel.pdf There is brief guidance from UK Gov here https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/cuba/entry-requirements

Comment: @Traveller That wasn't true in the case of Cuba; airlines and travel agents commit a crime if they aid a person evading OFAC regulations, per the Trading with the Enemy Act. ITA Matrix doesn't (or didn't) list Cuban airports for this reason. The situation really has improved in the last few years.

Comment: @Traveller Take a look at [this information](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/usa/entry-requirements#travelling-to-the-us-from-cuba) which I think is specific to UK citizens. It seems that travelling in this way is perfectly possible as long as your trip fits into the categories that I mentioned before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are not a US citizen nobody will ask you a question. Nothing to worry about. Just like any other international flight. Even if you were a US citizen, you just need to fill one page form when you fly from US to Cuba, not the other way around.

Comment: We flew this route with no problems whatsoever and I made a reminder to accept this answer and comment when we returned. There were zero questions at customs and we just had to fill out a landing card on the Cuba to Orlando flight.